# Casting Enum to uint

Tags: c#, enums

I'm writing a function that takes an `Enum` and casts it to `uint`. From what I've seen when casting to `int`, you have to cast it to an object first: `(int) (object) myEnumValue`. If you write `(int) myEnumValue` you get a compile time exception.

Now, when I tried to cast it to uint, I was expecting that `(uint) (object) myEnumValue` would be alright. It compiles nicely, but when run, it generates an `InvalidCastException`. So to get it to work, I've used

```
(uint) (int) (object) myEnumValue
```

I think it looks funny, so I'm quite happy, but why is it so?

Maybe it would have been more correct to ask why it is not possible to cast `object` to `uint`, but I'm interested in whether there is another way to go from an `Enum` to `uint`. Is there?

**Edit:**

The context is a function, something like this:

```
public static uint ToUInt (Enum e)
{
    return (uint) (int) (object) e;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

The best solution was as mentioned by thecoop:

```
Convert.ToUInt32(e)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `(uint) (object) myEnum` approach fails because, by default, C# enums use `int` as their underlying type, and an `int` is what they get turned into when they're boxed. The C# syntax makes it look like enums inherit from their underlying type (like `enum MyEnum : uint`).

You have to explicitly tell the compiler to unbox from `object` to `int` first, then do a numerical conversion from `int` to `uint`. (Even though the syntax is the same, unboxing from `object` to a value type is a different process from casting between `int` and `uint`.)

Comment: Ok, so if I specify my Enum as Enum : uint, it would be the other way around?

Comment: @Jonatan: yes, that would box the enum as uint, and you would be forced to unbox as uint.

Comment: That's right: (uint) e will be fine, but (int) e will blow up.

Comment: @Tim: inherit is a wrong term. You cannot inherit from `System.Int32` (maybe you can with some voodoo black magic, but that's not relevant). Enums inherit from `System.Enum`. What's correct to say is that the underlying type is `int`.

Comment: Er, you're right. And in this situation, what matters is that the enum is boxed to an int.

Comment: @thecoop, yes, and this could be the only practical way if you're not sure whether you're dealing with an int or a uint. Add your own answer and I'll upvote you :)

Answer (score 6):

> From what I've seen when casting to int, you have to cast it to an object first: `(int) (object) myEnum`. If you write `(int) myEnum` you get a compile time exception.

Not true. You can directly cast an enum value to an integer type.

> Now, when I tried to cast it to uint, I was expecting that (uint) (object) myEnum would be alright. It compiles nicely, but when run, it generates an InvalidCastException. So to get it to work, I've used: 
>          `(uint) (int) (object) myEnum`
>   I think it looks funny, so I'm quite happy, but why is it so?

When you cast an enum value to `object`, it'll be boxed as its *underlying type*, which is `int` by default. You cannot unbox a boxed value to any type other than its actual type directly. Even this will fail:

```
short s = 10;
object o = s;
int i = (int)o; // throws `InvalidCastException` while `int i = (int)s;` works.
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to go in the opposite direction, that is, from an underlying type to the enumeration of a particular type:

```
enum MyEnumType { a, b, c };
//...
MyEnumType enum_val = (MyEnumType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(MyEnumType), 2);
Console.WriteLine(enum_val == MyEnumType.c);
// "True"
```

I found this to be necessary (rather than simple casting) when authoring generic types. Since you can't use 'where' clauses to sufficiently constrain the generic <T> to your enumeration type, the compiler won't let you cast a numeric to it.